# Trading Card management system in Android SQLite

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am stuck on my code and been following the newboston tutorials on Youtube. Below is the code I have, but for some reason I am getting errors and I cannot figure this out, any tips?

this is my RedemptionDB.java class, in this code on the line

```
public RedemptionDB(Context c){
Context = c;
}
```

I Get an error telling me to set method return type void, but in the code Bucky does not have it that way.

The next error I get is in lines:

```
public RedmptionDB open(){
```

It tells me: Creat Class RedemptionDB, which is created I thought at the beginning of the code!

```
package com.aloadofbs.redemptioncardmanager;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class RedemptionDB {


private static final String DB_NAME = "RedempDB";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
private static final String TABLE = "cards";

public static final String KEY_ID = "_id"; // Special for id
public static final String KEY_CARDNUMBER = "card_number";
public static final String KEY_CARDNAME = "card_name";
public static final String KEY_BRIGCOLOR = "brig_color";
public static final String KEY_CARDPT = "power_toughness";
public static final String KEY_QTY = "qty";
public static final String KEY_VALUE = "value";
public static final String KEY_C = "C";
public static final String KEY_TYPE = "card_type";
public static final String KEY_SET = "card_set";
public static final String KEY_RARITY = "card_rarity";
public static final String KEY_VERSE = "card_verse";
public static final String KEY_IDENTIFIER = "card_identifiers";
public static final String KEY_ABILITIES = "card_special_ability";

private static DbHelper ourHelper;
private static Context ourContext;
private static SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }



@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + TABLE + " ("+ KEY_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ATOINCREMENT, " + KEY_CARDNUMBER + "TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_CARDNAME + "TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_BRIGCOLOR + "TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_CARDPT + "TEXT, " + KEY_QTY + "INTEGER, " + KEY_VALUE + "INTEGER, " + KEY_C + "TEXT, " + KEY_TYPE + "TEXT, " + KEY_SET + "TEXT, " + KEY_RARITY + "TEXT, " + KEY_VERSE + "TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_IDENTIFIER + "TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_ABILITIES + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
            );  

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE);
    onCreate(db);

}

public RedemptionDB (Context c){
Context = c;
}

public RedmptionDB open(){
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;

}

public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();
    ourDatabase.close();

}
}

public long createEntry(String cardname, String cardset,
        String cardcolor, String cardtype) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_CARDNAME, cardname);
    cv.put(KEY_BRIGCOLOR, cardcolor);
    cv.put(KEY_TYPE, cardtype);
    cv.put(KEY_SET, cardset);
    return ourDatabase.insert(TABLE, null, cv);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple changes should fix you up:

Change this:

```
public RedemptionDB(Context c){  
    Context = c;  
}
```

To this (you specifiec ourContext, not Context):

```
public RedemptionDB(Context c){  
    this.ourContext = c;  
}
```

Change this:

```
public DbHelper(Context context) { 
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION); 
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub 
}
```

To this (you really don't want that to be a public method):

```
DbHelper(Context context) { 
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION); 
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub 
}
```

Comment: I'll add that you also misspelled your class name in the open() method - "public RedmptionDB open()" should read "public RedemptionDB open()"